# Remove Data in a data frame based on an index column

Tags: r, if-statement

Looking at a Data Frame like so:

```
set.seed(3)
Data1<-rnorm(20, mean=20)
Dir_1<-rnorm(20,mean=2)
Data2<-rnorm(20, mean=21)
Dir_2<-rnorm(20,mean=2)
Data3<-rnorm(20, mean=22)
Dir_3<-rnorm(20,mean=2)
Data4<-rnorm(20, mean=19)
Dir_4<-rnorm(20,mean=2)
Data5<-rnorm(20, mean=20)
Dir_5<-rnorm(20,mean=2)
Data6<-rnorm(20, mean=23)
Dir_6<-rnorm(20,mean=2)
Data7<-rnorm(20, mean=21)
Dir_7<-rnorm(20,mean=2)
Data8<-rnorm(20, mean=25)
Dir_8<-rnorm(20,mean=2)
Index<-rnorm(20,mean=5)
DF<-data.frame(Data1,Dir_1,Data2,Dir_2,Data3,Dir_3,Data4,Dir_4,Data5,Dir_5,Data6,Dir_6,Data7,Dir_7,Data8,Dir_8,Index)
```

I end up with a data frame with two columns of data per observation (based on observation 1-8) and an index. Based on this index I would like to remove (or make NA) certain data observations.

As an example:

If the index is greater than 5, drop observation 8 (both  Data and Dir) in that row

If the index is greater than 4, drop observations 7 and 8 in that row

If the index is greater than 3 and less then 3.5, drop 6,7,8 in that row

I was hoping to come up with a series of "if" statements that would let me drop columns for each row based on an index value.

Comment: What do you mean "drop column for a row" ??????? Do you want to put NA in the respective column for that row?

Comment: You can not delete a different column for every row in a data.frame. It has to be the same column (or) as Theodore suggests, replace values with NA.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion. I would like to make the row, column location NA

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you want is not to "drop columns for a row" but put NAs into the proper columns for the rpecific row, you need to use a few index vectors and not a series of `if` statements:

```
DF[DF$Index>3 & DF$Index<3.5, (6*2-1):(8*2)] <- NA
DF[DF$Index>4, (7*2-1):(8*2)] <- NA
DF[DF$Index>5, (8*2-1):(8*2)] <- NA
```